# Electron MediaPlayPause globalShortcut binding on macOS Mojave

Tags: macos, electron, keyboard-shortcuts, macos-mojave, electron-builder

I'm working on a media player using Electron and I want to use the **globalShortcut** feature, but I noticed the Media Play/Pause (MediaPlayPause) accelerator is not registered successfully on macOS 10.14 Mojave unless the app has been authorized as a trusted accessibility client.
[Electron Documentation](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/global-shortcut)

Is there any workaround to avoid the user explicitly add the app manually to Security & Privacy tab under Accessibility? (For instance, Spotify is not under this section and the Play/Pause works really well as a globalShortcut)

If not, how can I request permission to the user to automatically allow the app to control the computer under Accessibility using Electron?

Thanks!

Comment: Martin: Did you find a way around this? I'm facing exact same issue. Thanks.